# Can I declare a local Array variable by reference, to reduce duplicate code

Tags: swift, reference

So I know that Swift Arrays are `struct`, so they are passed by value

Here is my code:

`firstSnapshotList` and `secondSnapshotList` are both `[Snapshot]`

```
    if datePicker == firstDatePicker {
        firstSnapshotList.removeAll()

        if let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] {
            for snapshot in snapshots {
                firstSnapshotList.append(snapshot)
            }
        }
    } else if datePicker == secondDatePicker {
        secondSnapshotList.removeAll()

        if let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] {
            for snapshot in snapshots {
                secondSnapshotList.append(snapshot)
            }
        }
    }
```

so as you can see, both blocks if the `if` statements are the same, except for the array being modified.

I would love to declare a variable first, `var snapshotList = *snapshot reference*`,
and then if I could set that reference to either `firstSnapshotList` or `secondSnapshotList` depending on the Date Picker, then my code would just be

```
if datePicker == firstDatePicker {
    snapshotList = firstSnapshotList
} else if datePicker == secondDatePicker {
    snapshotList = secondSnapshotList
}

snapshotList.removeAll()

if let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] {
    for snapshot in snapshots {
        snapshotList.append(snapshot)
    }
}
```

You could argue that the number of lines is the same, so it's not really any more readable or maintainable-- it's just personal preference for me, I think the second version makes more sense, mostly because there isn't any repeat code

But if this is just part of the Swift lifestyle, I can live with it too.  Just mostly wondering if it's even possible to declare a variable as a  reference

Comment: If you want to store array by reference, there is still a `class` solution of `NSMutableArray<Solution>`, so assigning is just referensing.
But also native collections are sharing internal memor, so in fact your stuct-array is not copied entirely, it just points to the same array, and when any of these "copies" attempts to modify its contents, a full internals copy is created to another instance and it  starts pointing to new buffer

Comment: also you can use `.append(contentsOf: snapshots)` which is also faster that adding by one

Comment: You could use `guard let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] else { return }` to deduplicate that part. Or write an extension `reset(with dateKey: String)` that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said Swift arrays are structs and these are indeed passed as values. You could instead pass the array to a separate method as an `inout` argument:

```
func yourMethodName(_ array: inout [Snapshot]) {
    array.removeAll()

    if let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] {
        for snapshot in snapshots {
            array.append(snapshot)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call the method where you need it like so:

```
if datePicker == firstDatePicker {
    yourMethodName(&firstSnapshotList)
} else if datePicker == secondDatePicker {
    yourMethodName(&secondSnapshotList)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Arrays, like all variable-size collections in the standard library, use copy-on-write optimization. Multiple copies of an array share the same storage until you modify one of the copies. When that happens, the array being modified replaces its storage with a uniquely owned copy of itself, which is then modified in place. Optimizations are sometimes applied that can reduce the amount of copying.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified to the point where there's no need to reduce code duplication:

```
let newSnapshotList = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] ?? []

if datePicker == firstDatePicker {
    firstSnapshotList = newSnapshotList
} else if datePicker == secondDatePicker {
    secondSnapshotList = newSnapshotList
}
```

But for the sake of answering the question, this can be done by declaring a nested function, within your existing function:

```
func overrideFromSnapshotDict(destination: inout [YourType]) {
    destination.removeAll()
    if let snapshots = SnapshotList.snapshotDict[dateKey] {
        for snapshot in snapshots {
            destination.append(snapshot)
        }
    }
}

if datePicker == firstDatePicker {
    overrideFromSnapshotDict(destination: &firstSnapshotList)
} else if datePicker == secondDatePicker {
    overrideFromSnapshotDict(destination: &secondSnapshotList)
}
```